# Laravel 6.12 seeding factory don't see states

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-seeding

As usual the project needed seeds.
And as usual I create a UserFactory, set it up, added to DatabasesSeeder and caught a error.

```
InvalidArgumentException  : Unable to locate [models] state for [App\Models\User]
```

but the default factory (I mean `$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker)`) is working fine

UserTableSeeder.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\User;

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory(User::class, 50)->state('models')->create();
        factory(User::class, 50)->create();
    }
}
```

UserFactory.php

```
use App\Models\User;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    //everything works fine here
});

$factory->defineAs(User::class, 'models', function (Faker $faker) {
    //exactly the same return except for a few string values
    //but 'Unable to locate [models] state for [App\Models\User]'
});
```

Comment: may I know the path where you store your user Model.

Comment: User namespace App\Models;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I was able to reproduce the error in my enviroment. Here's the problem. You gave the name `models` to you factory but called it as if it was a state. [$factory->defineAs](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.php#L79) (**Not documented**) does not define a factory with state but just give a name to your factory. **Factory States** and **Named Factories (yours)** are two different things. This is why you can't seed your database like it was a **State Factory**.

```
factory(User::class, 50)->state('models')->create();
```

If you want to use `$factory->defineAs` function, replace the above line with

```
factory(User::class,'models', 50)->create();
```

Or

**(Recommended - Because it's well documented)** If you still wish to be able to seed your database using `->state('models')` ([states](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#factory-states)), then change your `UserFactory.php` as follows

```
use App\Models\User;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    //everything works fine here
});

$factory->state(User::class, 'models', function (Faker $faker) {
    //exactly the same return except for a few string values
    //but 'Unable to locate [models] state for [App\Models\User]'
});
```

Remark: you now define your second factory with `$factory->state` and not `$factory->defineAs`.